# Unable to locate fields in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access, office365

I'm building a Contact list based off of the Contacts Template in Access. There are some calculated fields listed in the Field List that aren't present on the table itself. All I want to do is modify how they're calculated, specifically "File As" and "Contact Name". Does anyone know where I can modify the formulas used to calculate these fields? (Screenshot below)

[image: Screenshot of Field List]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find both those fields in query `Contacts Extended`.

Comment: Both of the comments were helpful and got me where I needed to be. This one was more direct.

Answer (score 2):

A more general solution:

Open the form properties, tab Data.

There you find the form `Record source` (the query the form gets its data from).
Click the `...` button at the right to open the query design.